# GWT: Does to much use of the $entry Function slows Application down?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, gwtp

I use the $entry function from GWT a lot in my JSNI function. I use them mostly in two cases:

1. when I create a new object in JSNI

   ```
   public static native KGroup create() /*-{
      var create = $entry(function() {
         return new $wnd.Kinetic.Group();
      });
      return create;
   }-*/;
   ```
2. When I attach an event handler somewhere

   ```
   public static native final KNodeEventCallbackJSO create(KNodeEventCallback callback)) /*-{
      var t = $entry(function(event) {
          callback.@com.test.KNodeEventCallback::onEvent(....)(event);
      });
      return t;
   }-*/;
   ```

**Does this slows my application down? Because ever time I use this GWT will add a try catch block to the JavaScript function.**

**Is there some rule of thumb when to use $entry and when don't?**

Comment: Du you use a UncaughtExceptionHandler? And do you call it with a deferred Command?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach should I do it this way? What is the advantage and what does this have to do with my question?

Comment: There are several big things that `$entry` magically solves for you - one is catching otherwise uncaught Java exceptions and passing them to your UncaughtExceptionHandler. Another is running scheduled commands. If you plan on using either feature, using `$entry` properly is important. From that, its hard to say if you *need* it in either example, because you don't show what you do with the return values from those methods.

Comment: @ColinAlworth I use the return values from this methods as JavaScriptObjects wrapped objects of http://kineticjs.com/. Then I work a lot with these objects on the Java side. I.e., I do a lot of HTML5 canvas operations where these kind of objects are involved. So will entry has any problems with performance in this case? Do you have a rule of thumb when to use it?

Comment: You are doing it right. When ever you pass a Java/GWT method call out to plain JS (which includes other GWT modules not compiled into the same project), use `$entry` to make sure the pieces mentioned above stay working. See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling. I'll do a more complete answer writeup if you think this is helping.

Comment: @ColinAlworth yes this helps you can do a more complex answer. Thank you.